# Conditional proxy settings in gradle.properties

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy

I use Android Studio and gradle in my office using a authenticated corporate proxy. This unfortunately means that I have to enter my proxy config including user/pass in cleartext in `gradle.properties` (or have it automatically propagated from Android Studio's preferences).

However, sometimes I work outside of the office, and I then have to manually go in and comment out my proxy settings each time, which is tedious.

Is there a way to make properties in a gradle file conditional so that the proxy configuration can be automatically activated by detecting if I'm on my corporate network or not? The condition itself could in turn be retrieved either by querying the network adapter for the current network, or perhaps better, by making a simple curl to a known host on my corporate network.

I'm using both Windows and Ubuntu clients but this question mostly applies to Windows.

There might be other ways to solve this I guess, perhaps changing the global gradle settings rather than the project specific ones. To be honest, I have to do a similar `git config --add http.proxy`, and the same for `npm`, `bower` and what not, everytime I change working environments. Other suggestions are welcome even though this question specifically asks how to create a `gradle.properties` which tries to connect to a known intranet host, and depending on the outcome sets or unsets properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for a while. There was an additional problem for me that `gradle.properties` are checked in to our VCS with a proxy setting; and I had to take extra steps before all my commits to ignore the changes I did in that file. Additionally, I had to comment/uncomment the same piece of code multiple times in a day.

I could not come up with a conditional update system, but the second problem was resolved by inbuilt shelving functionality in Android Studio and creating changelists to keep 2 copies of the file with different settings.

I don't think there is any way to solve this problem the way you are asking for. For a simple reason: .properties files are not meant to have logic. To quote the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html):

> Properties are configuration values managed as **key/value pairs**.

The dynamic settings can be achieved either via Android Studio proxy settings or writing a Gradle task that runs on project load, checks network conditions and sets system properties. I haven't tested this approach, but I think this will also update the gradle.properties file (a side-effect that you may not want). But what is being done by Gradle can also be done via a shell script that you need to execute on project load.

The way I am currently handling proxy update is by entering/saving the proxy settings in Android Studio itself, and toggling when I move between locations. It just takes a couple of commands to bring up the proxy dialog and enable/disable the saved proxy.

Since this proxy file is saved in `idea.config.path/options/proxy.settings.xml`, you could also try writing a shell script that can toggle the contents based on network availability.

This may not be what you were looking for, but I hope it clears up why it can't be done the way you asked for.